# NSSM service does not show GUI

Tags: java, maven, service, windows-services, nssm

I have a maven/java project i am trying to make a windows service. I have a .exe which is used to distribute the program, and now I need to make it a windows service.

The executable works fine by itself and shows the GUI.

I have ran everything in elevated cmd & powershell terminals.

When i install the service: NSSM_TEST: INSTALL: The operation completed successfully.

When i start the service: NSSM_TEST: START: The operation completed successfully.

When i run status: nssm.exe status NSSM_TEST SERVICE_RUNNING

The program also shows up under the running processes, but shows no gui or system tray symbol (which is implemented through java).

Parameters in mssn GUI:

Application path: C:\Users\skakk\sweat-tek\DynaGrow\DynaGrow-app\target\dynagrow\bin\dynagrow.exe

Startup Directory: C:\Users\skakk\sweat-tek\DynaGrow\DynaGrow-app\target\dynagrow\bin

No arguments.

Log on config:

[image: LogOnConfig1]

[image]

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Same for me for a .NET application: I see the app under the background processes in the Task Manager but it is not visible. How can we solve it?

Comment: @Oskar Did you mange to solve the issue ?

Comment: @rojarand No unfortunately. As far as I've understood, it actually can not be solved, as the service framework in windows no longer supports GUI's. That means a service should be a non-gui API.